# Python to interact with Youtube

Tags: python, youtube

I have started learning how to code in python and so far I've been doing normal exercises and I have an idea using which I want to explore more on python. It goes something like this.

1. User is listening to music on his computer using some media player.
2. If he/she plays any video on YouTube, then the music on his computer must be paused. And when the video is completed, the music should resume.

I'm not asking for code, obviously. I just want to know what concepts should I look into for accomplishing this task.

And I am sure there will be someone who have already made this. I am just trying to make this so that I can learn some different concepts in Python.

Edit:: After looking at the comments, I am making some changes to my question and tags. I want to do this application with this particular setup - Chrome browser - Windows Media Player - Windows 8

Is this a good enough task for a beginner to use as an excuse to learn Python?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So you need to write a daemon able to (A) detect every "some media player" you want to support and interact with said player to the extent of knowing if it's playing, make it suspend, make it resume; (B) detect if any browser is playing a youtube video and whether that video is completed (what if the video gets paused before completion?).  Very hard with any generality!  So to start pick one single OS platform with top flexibility (Linux sounds good), one single browser easy to add extensions to (Chrome sounds good),  one single player w/a great API (no idea here).  Still LOTS of work!-)

Comment: Oh and BTW I doubt GAE has anything to do with the task -- it seems pretty much entirely a client-side job, with no substantial role to play for a server-side component which is what you could use GAE to add, so I'd recommend editing your tags, removing GAE, and later adding something more useful once you've picked a OS platform, a specific player, a specific browser.